# Botón deja de funcionar al rotar dispositivo

Tags: java, android, audio

Estoy haciendo una "aplicación" que consta de una pista de audio con sus botones play y pause. El caso es que cuando inicio la aplicación todo funciona correctamente, le das al play y suena la pista, le das al pause y se pausa, le das al play otra vez y se reanuda, todo bien hasta ahí... pero cuando roto el dispositivo, si antes de rotarlo estaba sonando la pista de audio, el botón pause deja de funcionar... No entiendo qué pasa, he probado de todo y leído de todo pero no consigo avanzar. He leído sobre el método onRestoreInstanceState e intentado hacer algo con él pero tampoco, nada. Dejo mi código a ver si me podéis echar una mano. Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

```
package com.example.pista;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button btnPistaPlay, btnPistaPause;
MediaPlayer musica;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        musica = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pista);

        btnPistaPlay = findViewById(R.id.btnPistaPlay);
        btnPistaPause = findViewById(R.id.btnPistaPause);

        btnPistaPause.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnPistaPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnPistaPlay:
            musica.start();
            break;
        case R.id.btnPistaPause:
            musica.pause();
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Buenas @Guts , creo que este enlace podría ayudar a resolver tu inconveniente [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917994/how-to-play-audio-continuously-while-orientation-changes-in-android/31466602) , en particular comprobé la respuesta 4 del usuario **anfd** la cual si bien tiene el inconveniente de pausar y volver a continuar la reproducción el mismo cumple la solución del inconveniente.

Answer (score 2):

**Lo que sucede es que al girar el dispositivo, la `Activity` que esta realizando la reproducción es destruida y se genera nuevamente deteniendo la reproducción y reiniciando el estado de los elementos.**

Una forma de evitar estos problemas relacionados a la reproducción es definir dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` en la Activity `android:configChanges="orientation"`.

Ejemplo:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```

> si se declara una configuración con este atributo, la actividad no se
>   reiniciará. En cambio, la actividad permanece en ejecución y se llama
>   al método

Revisa:

[Cómo manejar cambios en la configuración](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html?hl=es)